# Approach to solve $(3^\frac{2}{7} - 2^\frac{3}{7} ) * 112$

Tags: power-series, arithmetic, fractions

Question:

**$$(3^\frac{2}{7}-2^\frac{3}{7}) * 112 = ?$$**

How should i approach such question ?
First look, i tried to make power fractions equal for both the individual expressions. Like the following:

$$3^\frac{2}{7}-2^\frac{3}{7}=9^\frac{1}{7}-8^\frac{1}{7}$$

Now this looks like :

$$(a^x-b^x) or (a^x-(a-1)^x)$$

or may be :

$$a^x*(1-(\frac{a-1}{a})^x)$$

or instead of doing this, should i go with approximation by considering $9^\frac{1}{7}$ close to $9^\frac{1}{8}$ and then taking square root 3 times ?

or is there any specific reason to multiply this expression by 112 ?

Need some help figuring out the solution.

I do not want to use any calc for this and am trying to figure out a few possible approaches which can give me an approximate result with atleast 2 decimal point accuracy if possible.

Comment: You can use a scientific calculator. About $2.5578463691027$.

Comment: Hmm. I think i know about scientific calculator. I am a bit curious about what if i do not have one. Can it be solved out without a scalc ? An approximate result will also do good.

Comment: Maybe you should state that.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I will mention this.

Comment: Is taking the square root allowed ??

Comment: We know the answers for sqrt(3) and sqrt(2). So i felt i can use them straight forward if required.

Comment: But you mentioned "taking square root 3 times" !

Comment: Yes. I think it should not be a huge problem doing it without calculator. As i mentioned i need an approximation for this. So i know sqrt(9) is 3 and sqrt(3) is 1.72 and sqrt(1.72) is around 1.32. How ? because i know 13*13 = 169 and 14*14 = 196.

Comment: You are asking for $3$ exact decimals, this is another matter. What is the eighth root of $8$ ?

Comment: i know that sqrt(2) is 1.414. now sqrt(8) is 2*1.414 = 2.828. Again sqrt(2.82) should be close to 1.66 or 1.67 as i know 16*16 = 256 and 17*17 = 289. Now sqrt(1.67) is around 1.29.

Comment: Yep, but as the final answer is about 2.5 after multiplication by 112, you need to compute the roots with five exact decimals, not 2.

Comment: Right. I edited my question. I do not have any hard and fast requirement for accuracy. All i need to know is what can be the possible ways to solve it out with best possible accuracy and with no use of calc. Thanks.

Comment: When i came across this question i had no way to access calc. So i thought there might be something to solve this out by hand and ofcourse i was given 4 choices which were not very close in terms of numbers after decimal points.

Comment: If you have choices, that's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my life depended on it, I would probably compute the seventh roots of $8$ and $9$ in base $2$ with the root algorithm used in written computation. Omitting details (the algorithms is actually a dichotomic search), the crucial step in the algorithm is to compute

$$(2x+1)^7,$$ where $x$ is an approximation. You can do this using the Binomial expansion (and noting that multiplying by a power of $2$ is a mere shift). The coefficients are $1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1$ (decimal).

But I guess that the computation via $y^7=y\,y^2(y^2)^2$ will be faster/simpler.

Next you convert to base $10$ and multiply by $112$. A first step is to determine the number of significant bits required. Count two of three hours of work.

---

Alternatively, the seventh roots can be evaluated by Newton-Raphson, but this will take the evaluation of sixths powers and divisions.

---

Another interesting alternative is the secant method, starting from the inequalities

$$1.3^7=6.2748517<8<9<1.4^7=10.5413504.$$

As the curve is pretty flat, the next estimates are obtained by linear interpolation. Optionally, when a new approximation is obtained, it can be truncated to a smaller number of decimals to ease the evaluation of the seventh power.

For example, the next approximation of $\sqrt[7]8$ is $1.340434755\cdots$, and you can use $1.34$ instead.

---

If you have a fast way to compute the square roots, by some magic, you can use the fixed-point iteration

$$x\leftarrow \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{yx}}},$$ the solution of which is $x=y^{1/7}$.

Comment: Thanks. The third one looks interesting. I am not accepting it at this point as i would like to know other similar approaches from others. But your answer is satisfactory and i will be accepting it after a while. Thanks again.

Comment: @Shasha99 Changing the statement after the fact is cheating. And you still need to compute the roots to four exact decimals.

Comment: I did not change any statement. As you were focusing much on accuracy instead of the possible solution, i just changed accuracy to 2 decimal points instead of 3. And yes, i still need to compute the roots to four exact decimals.

Comment: @Shasha99: so what's the eighth root of $8$ to four decimals ?

Comment: "or instead of doing this, should i go with approximation by considering 9^1/7 close to 9^1/8 and then taking square root 3 times ?"  This was my question. Intention was to understand which way is easier to go with ? However i can see that you are taking it otherwise. Your wish. Anyways ,Thanks for sharing the approaches.

Comment: @Shasha99: not at all. I kept asking about the eighth root of eight when what is needed is the seventh root of eight. I think you missed that. I also gave the solution to obtain seventh roots from three iterated square roots. I have done more than enough.